# RewriteCond: 2 parameters for QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am dealing with an API that is accessing an URL on my website and adding
`/?parameter1=value&parameter2=value` to the url. I want my htaccess to handle this request and only keep the parameter's values. The API is also adding many other parameters in the query string but I just want to keep two of them.

The following does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter1=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter2=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^my-url/?$ controller.php?parameter1=%1&parameter2=%2
```

How can I do that correctly?

EDIT:

Here is an example.

```
The url is:
http://example.com/my-url/?parameter1=value1&stuff=1&stuff2=2&parameter2=value2
```

The htaccess should get the parameter1 & parameter2 values.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? A before url and after url?

Comment: Howlin: Example added.

Comment: You can just use the `QSA` flag and just get the two parameters you want in your code.

Comment: Will there always be two parameters between parameter1 and parameter2?

Comment: Howlin, there are not always the same parameters. The thing I know is that parameter1 and parameter2 will be there somewhere.

Comment: @PeterLur if parameter1 is always there, the code I gave you will work for what you are asking.

Comment: @Panama Jack: Isnt there an easier way just to select the two parameters directly in the htaccess without having to process the whole $_GET later on?

Comment: The reason your original redirect doesn't work is that RewriteCond backreferences only work for the last RewriteCond statement. So it would work for `parameter2` in your example, but not `parameter1`.

Comment: @PeterLur That doesn't matter, it doesn't make your code any slower or faster. All you have to do is just get the value directly for the two you want. `$_GET["parameter1"]` and `$_GET["parameter2"]`. Doesn't matter if there are others in array. It's no different than `$_SERVER` var, which contains many parameters that you may or may not use. It's just there.

Comment: @Panama Jack: You are right. It could work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and just grab the two parameters in your server side code. e.g. `$_GET`.  If they are always in the query string, you can just check for `parameter1` and then it will append the other parameters and you can get what you need.

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\bparameter1=
 RewriteRule ^my-url/?$ controller.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what the [QSA,L] does exactly? I don't understand why the parameters are being appended to the Rewrite. It works but I would like to know why.

Comment: Nevermind found it: QSA means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite. Thanks!

Comment: The QSA flag stands for `QUERY STRING APPEND`.. This will explain it better for you http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa. It is a very helpful flag when dealing with query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /my-url/\?parameter1=(.*)&stuff=(.*)&stuff2=(.*)&parameter2=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /controller.php?parameter1=%2&parameter2=%5\? [R,L]
```

Mind it will only get the two parameters if there are **always** `&stuff=1&stuff2=2` those two values in the url.

Comment: Howlin, there are not always the same parameters. The thing I know is that parameter1 and parameter2 will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do a similar setup with key/value pairs in the GET which could come in any order depending on the client platform.

Based on useful pointers in this thread, this is what I came up with based on the question above:

```
#= 1. Catch parameter1, append querystring as "p1=". Rewrite to "/parameter1" below:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/my-url/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter1=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) /parameter1?%{QUERY_STRING}&p1=%1 [P,QSD]

#= 2. Catch parameter2, append querystring as "p2=". Rewrite to "/parameter2" below:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/parameter1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter2=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) /parameter2?%{QUERY_STRING}&p2=%1 [P,QSD]

#= 3. Now explicitly catch p1,p2 and feed to them to the back-end url:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/parameter2$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p1\=([^&]+)&p2\=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) controller.php?parameter1=%1&parameter2=%2 [P,L,QSD]
```

The above works fine for me but I do notice it a tiny bit slow to process, so if anyone has any criticism then I would be glad to hear it!